# Android custom font won't bold unless done programmatically

Tags: android, fonts, android-xml

As the title suggests I have custom fonts for regular, bold, etc. When I set the font to bold or italic in the xml it will show in the design but not appear on an actual device (Samsung galaxy s9). I've tried a couple different strategies and the only way I can get it to work correctly is by setting the font programmatically.

```
Typeface boldFont = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), R.font.cogito_bold);
testTextView.setTypeface(boldFont);
```

Here's is where the xml layout for the textview is

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="44sp"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/cogito_font"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Test Words"
    android:textColor="@color/wb_white" />
```

Here is my custom font family, and then I have the .otf files in the same res/font directory. I have also tried just setting the textview's fontfamily directly to the cogito_bold.otf with no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:font="@font/cogito_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/cogito_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

    <font
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:font="@font/cogito_italic"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/cogito_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

    <font
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:font="@font/cogito_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/cogito_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700" />
</font-family>
```

Comment: Probably because your font is not included in google fonts

Comment: google font family available can be found via; design > click your textview > attributes Tabs > font family > click dropdown > more fonts...(at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without creating a font family.
Just add the fonts to the res>**font** directory.

> app_font_bold.ttf
>
> app_font_regular.ttf

And call the font in the XML.

```
android:fontFamily="@font/app_font_bold"
```

Comment: I created the font family to make it easy to bold by just adding the styling to it. I believe the issue was that the base activity I was extending from was causing issues with the font. Changing it to extend AppCompatActivity seemed to fix the issue.